# Full page with two vertical responsive images with link without background

Tags: html, css, image

I can't use

```
background:
```

for this task. Because it can not be linked.

So far i made this:

```
.fullpage img {
height: 50vh;
width: 100vw;
}
```

The problem is with vw image is stretched.

Edit:

I also found complete solution with:

```
object-fit:cover;
```

But you need to use it directly in img tag.

Or define class with img like this:

```
.fullpage img {
height: 50vh;
width: 100vw;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

I had trouble with this task, for hours, so I wanted to share it. Is this good enough. Or there is better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not important if a part of the image is not displayed I would create two divs and put the two images centered in a div and make them fill the whole div with overflow on hidden, preserving the aspect ratio. And then use the following CSS and HTML:

Working demo:

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.full {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img class="full" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="full" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"/>
</div>
```

NOTE: The top image is a big portait image to show that the scaling works correctly, although it does not look nice. It is of course better to use two landscape images which provides a much better result.

Comment: Thank you, Sven, it helped me back then, just forgot to say thanks :)